# Number of biquadrates mod n

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory, multiplicative-number-theory, algorithms

Is there an explicit formula for the number of fourth powers mod n?

Finch & Sebah [1] give theorems, partially folklore, for squares and cubes mod n, but I don't know of a similar formula for higher powers.

[1] S. R. Finch and Pascal Sebah, [Squares and Cubes Modulo n](http://arXiv.org/abs/math.NT/0604465)

Comment: Reduce to the case $n$ is a prime power, then it's straightforward.

Comment: @Geoff: Of course it's multiplicative by inspection (or the CRT, I suppose).

Comment: @Charles: Yes, by the CRT. Now add the fact that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has a simple structure when $n$ is a prime power (it is cyclic or the 2-element group times a cyclic group).

Comment: The number of distinct fourth powers modulo $n$ is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A052273 and the link https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/1390691 is given to Shuguang Li, On the number of elements with maximal order in the multiplicative group modulo $n$, Acta Arithmetica 1998;86(2):113–32 with particular reference to the proof of Theorem 2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72201/number-of-biquadrates-mod-n#comment182932_72201) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72201/number-of-biquadrates-mod-n#comment182983_72201) [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72201/number-of-biquadrates-mod-n#comment183408_72201)), the counting function is multiplicative, so only the prime power case needs to be addressed. Last year, I derived a somewhat concise formula for $\lvert R_k (p^m)\rvert$, where $R_k (p^m)$ is the set of $k$-th power residues (not necessarily coprime to the modulus) modulo $p^m$. It was recently accepted for publication: [Counting general power residues](https://doi.org/10.7546/nntdm.2022.28.4.730-743). Here is the result, quoted from the paper:

> Let $\epsilon$ be the parity function. So for integers $t$, $
>  \epsilon(t) = \begin{cases}
>      0 &\text{ if } 2\mid t\\
>      1 &\text{ if } 2\nmid t. \end{cases} $
>
> Let $p$ be a prime, and $k\ge 2$ and $m\ge 1$ be integers. Let $r$ be
> the remainder of $m$ upon division by $k$. Let \begin{align*}
>      \alpha &= \dfrac{p-1}{(k,p-1)},\\
>      \beta &= (\nu_p (k)+1)(1-\epsilon(k))(1-\epsilon(p))+\nu_p(k)\epsilon (p),\\
>      \gamma &=
>      \begin{cases}
>          k &\text{ if } k \mid m\\
>          r &\text{ if } k\nmid m.
>      \end{cases}. \end{align*} Then \begin{align*} \lvert R_k (p^m)\rvert &= \alpha \cdot \left(\dfrac{p^k}{p^{\beta +1}}\cdot
>  \dfrac{p^m-p^{\gamma}}{p^k-1}+
>  \left\lceil\dfrac{p^{\gamma}}{p^{\beta+1}}\right\rceil\right)+1\\ &=
>  \alpha \cdot \left\lceil\dfrac{1}{p^{\beta +1}}\cdot
>  \dfrac{p^{m+k}-p^{\gamma}}{p^k-1}\right\rceil+1. \end{align*}
>
> (Note that the $\dfrac{p^k}{p^{\beta +1}}\cdot
>  \dfrac{p^m-p^{\gamma}}{p^k-1}$ term is necessarily an integer, so it
> can be absorbed into the ceiling term
> $\left\lceil\dfrac{p^{\gamma}}{p^{\beta+1}}\right\rceil$ as shown.)

Obviously the proof is what matters, but computational testing matched the results of the formulas in all cases tried.

**References:** My initial inspiration was a paper [Counting squares in $\mathbb Z_n$](https://doi.org/10.1080/0025570X.1996.11996456) of Walter Stangl, who addressed the quadratic case. Also, my discussion with Arturo Magidin in [Is there a known formula for the number of $k^{\text{th}}$ power residues modulo $2^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796985/is-there-a-known-formula-for-the-number-of-k-textth-power-residues-modulo) was helpful in the derivation. After submission to the first journal that I tried, a reviewer noted that similar formulas were mentioned by Maxim Korolev in [On the average number of power residues modulo a composite number](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010IzMat..74.1225K/abstract) ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.1070/IM2010v074n06ABEH002522)), who himself referred to a paper [The Number of kth Power Residues Modulo m](http://njsfdxzrb.paperonce.org/oa/darticle.aspx?type=view&id=200101001) of Ji Chungang.

**Note:** Given the content of the above references, the originality of my minor contribution rests only on unifying the various cases by noticing their similarities, summing a series that the others left unclosed, and expanded elementary exposition. I am not surprised that I was able to publish it only after trying a couple of other more well-known journals first, but it was a little surprising that the arXiv rejected posting it.

Comment: Perhaps your formula, case $k=4$, should be recorded at https://oeis.org/A052273

Comment: Definitely looking forward to the paper!

Comment: @Charles here you go: https://doi.org/10.7546/nntdm.2022.28.4.730-743

Comment: @GerryMyerson After a few days of collaborating with the OEIS editors, the updates have been posted: https://oeis.org/A052273 . Also, the OEIS page and its various crossref pages noted conjectures of Richard Mathar on the subject. I have managed to modify my formula to prove them all. I sent off the resolution of these predicted formulas to the arXiv (which once again put it on hold) and a journal. Thanks for linking me to the OEIS page.